# Is there something similar to automysqlbackup for backing up regular files and directories?

Tags: backup

I am using simple TAR and GZIP tools to back up data. Now I found how great `automysqlbackup` tool is. I especially like it for its ability to make daily / weekly / monthly / latest back ups. Is there some similar tool which can be so easily used for backing up regular data - files and directories ?

I am especially looking for something very easily configurable (possibly similar to automysqlbackup config). I would also appreciate if this tool could do daily backups just for changed files (so I don't have tons of the same not-changed picture files in every daily backup, just in week and month backup).

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

rdiff-backup (the actual backup) + backupninja (for scheduling)

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying [backuppc](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/)? It has web-based interface and supports multiple backup tools. It supports full/incremental backups as well.